# Plot a graph relating to the Granger Causality Test

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I have used the code below to run a Granger causality test on a data frame that I have. The code runs fine and returns the correct results that I would expect, however, I was wondering if it is possible to plot the data in a graph using python showing the causality?

Something similar to this:
[image]

I have tried using the code below and have been successful in returning data.

```
print(grangercausalitytests(df[['Number_of_Ethereum_Searches', 'Price_in_USD']], maxlag=1, addconst=True, verbose=True))
```

Comment: Pandas has a `DataFrame.plot` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html.  Will that help?

Comment: I have tried that however i have been unsuccessful

Comment: If you can post a section of your code or sample data from your output, that might help.  I don''t know where Granger might come into play here. Your visualization example is super helpful, though; I just can't picture what the data looks like that you're trying to plot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to inspect this visually, then you should use a cross-correlation diagram. This illustrates the strength of the correlation between two time series.

Let's illustrate this with an example. Consider the following two variables:

- Sunlight hours
- Maximum temperature

Ever notice how July/August are the hottest months in the Northern Hemispehere, while the longest day is on June 21? This is due to a a time lag, where the effects of maximum sunlight do not cause a maximum temperature until a month later or so.

If one were to plot a cross-correlation function to describe this, here is what it would look like (code included).

```
# Import Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import quandl
import scipy.stats as ss
import os;

# Set Path
path="directory"
os.chdir(path)
os.getcwd()

# Variables
dataset=np.loadtxt("dataset.csv", delimiter=",")
x=dataset[:,1]
y=dataset[:,0]
plt.xcorr(x, y, normed=True, usevlines=True, maxlags=365)
plt.title("Sunlight Hours versus Maximum Temperature")
plt.show()
```

**Cross-Correlation Diagram**

[image]

The ACF (autocorrelation) and PACF (partial autocorrelation) plots for these can also be plotted.

```
# Autocorrelation
acfx=statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf(x)
plt.plot(acfx)
plt.title("Autocorrelation Function")
plt.show()
pacfx=statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf(x)
plt.plot(pacfx)
plt.title("Partial Autocorrelation Function")
plt.show()
acfy=statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf(y)
plt.plot(acfy)
plt.title("Autocorrelation Function")
plt.show()
pacfy=statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf(y)
plt.plot(pacfy)
plt.title("Partial Autocorrelation Function")
plt.show()
```

**Autocorrelation and Partial Autocorrelation plots (Maximum temperature)**

[image]

[image]

**Autocorrelation and Partial Autocorrelation plots (Sunlight hours)**

[image]

[image]

Notice how the strength of the correlations for sunlight hours persist for longer than maximum temperature, which implies that the effects of long sunlight hours persist in influencing temperature (i.e. one is Granger-causing the other).

Hope the above example is helpful. I would suggest looking at both cross-correlations and autocorrelations in order to get a better overview of the nature of Granger causality in your data.